# How to remove an element from an unevenly shaped array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, filter

```
labels_1 = np.array([[-100,32,34,25,2,35,2,5,-100,-100],[-100,35,2,5,-100,-100]])
pred_1 = np.array([[8,32,3,25,2,3,2,5,8],[8,3,2,5,8]])
```

I want to get rid of the -100s in labels_1 and get the correspondingly matching index elements from pred_1.

for eg the output should be

```
labels_1 = np.array([[32,34,25,2,35,2,5],[35,2,5]])
pred_1 = np.array([[32,3,25,2,3,2,5],[3,2,5]])
```

I tried to use `np.where(labels_1!=-100)` but it only works for arrays with lists of same lengths, but as you can see the arrays in labels_1 have different lengths and that is a problem.

Comment: no ragged arrays in numpy... (heed the loud warnings).

Comment: That array contains lists, effectively jt's a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```py
pred_1 = [[b for a, b in zip(la, lb) if a != -100] for la, lb in zip(labels_1, pred_1)]
labels_1 = [[a for a in la if a != -100] for la in labels_1]
```

Outcome:

```py
>>> labels_1
[[32, 34, 25, 2, 35, 2, 5], [35, 2, 5]]

>>> pred_1
[[32, 3, 25, 2, 3, 2, 5], [3, 2, 5]]
```

As said in the comments, you cannot represent ragged arrays in `numpy`. If you try as you wrote it, you should see a loud `VisibleDeprecationWarning`, indicating that your result will be a list of lists, and that if you really intend to do this, you should specify 'dtype=object'... You could look into masked arrays, if that fits your needs better, but otherwise you're better off with simple lists (of lists, in this case).

**Edit**

Although a bit more convoluted, the following is perhaps more generalizable (any condition involving either or both of `a` and `b`, where `a` and `b` are elements of one array and the other, respectively):

```py
labels_1, pred_1 = map(list, zip(*[
    list(map(list, zip(*[
        (a, b) for a, b in zip(la, lb)
        if a != -100  # you can adapt this condition at will
    ])))
    for la, lb in zip(labels_1, pred_1)
]))
```

This is more flexible. For example, it would let you select elements in both arrays when one is larger than the other, or any condition on the pair of elements.

Comment: sure -- there is something puzzling me though: not only are your arrays ragged, they are also of different lengths. There might be no "correspondingly matching elements" in `pred_1`. Did I miss something?

Comment: are you trying to say that there might be a case where len(labels_1[i]) != len(pred_1[i])? That won't happen cos both of these arrays are being generated following the same process being applied to them simultaneously. (apologies if i misunderstood your question, i am not that proficient with pythonic jargons atm). Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: no worries; in your example, the sublists are indeed of different length between `labels_1` and `pred_1`: `list(map(len, labels_1))  # gives [10, 6)` whereas `list(map(len, pred_1))  # gives [9, 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

By having unevenly-sized lists in your numpy arrays, you defeat the purpose of numpy arrays, so you can use numpy solutions for this.

Nevertheless, you can use list comphrension for this task:

```
labels_1 = np.array([[x for x in y if x != -100] for y in labels_1])
pred_1 = np.array([[x for x in y if x != -100] for y in pred_1])
```

Output:

```
>>> labels_1
array([list([32, 34, 25, 2, 35, 2, 5]), list([35, 2, 5])], dtype=object)

>>> pred_1
array([list([8, 32, 3, 25, 2, 3, 2, 5, 8]), list([8, 3, 2, 5, 8])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, you got the labels_1 part correct, however for pred_1, i don't want -100s removed(that array doesn't have any), I want the elements corresponding to the indexes of the retained elements from labels_1. please check the output of pred_1. thanks

Comment: Ah, okay. Let me see...